# Relationship between a Probability Distribution Function and a Probability Transition Matrix

Tags: probability

I am trying to understand the relationship between a Probability Distribution Function and a Probability Transition Matrix.

For example, consider the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm):

*In the MCMC algorithm, the idea is to define a Markov chain over possible
values, in such a way that the stationary distribution of the Markov Chain is in fact $p(x)$ . That is, what we’re going to do is use a Markov chain to generate a sequence of
values $x$, denoted by $x_1, x_2,...x_n$ , in such a way that as $n \to \infty$
, we can guarantee that $x_n \sim p(x)$* (https://blog.djnavarro.net/posts/2023-04-12_metropolis-hastings/)

This to me seems as we are comparing "apples to oranges". For example:

- A probability distribution function $p(x)$ does not have a transition matrix. For some probability distribution function $p(x)$, all we know is the probability of observing some range of $x$ values. A probability distribution function is a static object.
- In a (Discrete Time) Markov Chain, the Stationary Distribution is a vector of probabilities. This tells us, what is the probability of being in a specific state at some time point (such that no change occurs to these probabilities in the next time step)
- A probability distribution does not have a Stationary Distribution. There is no probability of a probability distribution occupying a specific "state". The probability distribution only tells us the probability of occupying a specific range of $x$ values

Thus, using my logic, it seems like we are going in circles here. What does it even mean for   "as $n \to \infty$, we can guarantee that $x_n \sim p(x)$" ? For example, in a Normal Distribution, there is 0 probability of observing exactly 2.31 ... and there is 0 probability of "transitioning" from 2.31 to 2.32. So how can some sequence of x's from a Markov Chain have the same distribution as some probability distribution function?

Can someone please help me understand this?

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to understand that a Markov chain can be defined by a transition matrix and can have a stationary distribution and that these are not the same thing. The passage you've quoted doesn't say they're the same thing either. What's the confusion?

Comment: Looking at an MCMC example would probably clarify things. As to what "as $n\to\infty, x_n\sim p$" means, this is [convergence in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Definition).

Comment: @stats_noob: I think you are right to make this point because it is confusing, atleast to me.  I think of it as the following:  when they say "probability distribution" with respect to a markov chain, what they are really saying ( but I've never seen it said ) is that each "state" has its own probability distribution. So, if you have a 3 by 3 transition matrix, the first row has a discrete probability distribution which is $p_{(1,1)}, p_{(1,2)}, p_{(1,3)}$. The same holds for the second row and third row. Note that, in continuous time, this argument doesn't hold.

Comment: @ mark leeds: thank you so much for your reply! So in the case of MCMC, if I am trying to sample from some complex distribution g(x) .... then within  the markov chain constructed by MCMC , p(1,1) would have distribution g(x) ... p(1,2) would have distribution g(x)  ...etc etc... p(3,3) would have distribution g(x) ?

Comment: A Markov chain gives you a sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,...$ with corresponding probability distributions $p_1,p_2,...$. The limit of these distributions (if it exists) is a stationary distribution of the Markov chain. The idea of MCMC is to set up the Markov chain in such a way that this stationary distribution is the desired distribution $p$.

Comment: @ karl: thank you for your reply! I am afraid I don't fully understand... Suppose there are N states in a (Discrete Time) Markov Chain. The way I see it, X1, X2 ...represents which state the Markov Chain is currently in at time point 1,2 ... etc.  There are finite states in a Discrete Time Markov Chain -the stationary distribution refers to the probability of being in any of these finite states at some limit. On the other hand, the desired distribution p is continuous. I am having difficulty understanding how to equate the concept of the stationary distribution (of the mc) to a continuous pdf?

Comment: I see. This Markov chain will have infinitely many states (so it can't be defined by a transition matrix). In general a Markov chain is specified by a conditional distribution $p(X_{n+1}|X_n)$, which doesn't have to be a discrete distribution.

Comment: @ karl: thank you again for your kind reply. I think I understand the purpose of the metropolis-hastings algorithm - create a markov chain that is able to generate samples more likely to belong to the high density regions of the desired distribution, thus making the algorithm more efficient compared to acceptance-rejection sampling. But this is where I get confused: I understand this markov chain can have a stationary distribution - the probability of being in any given  state in the long run (infinite number of states - thus matching the support of the desired pdf).

Comment: So if we could hypothetically write the stationary distribution of the markov chain produced by metropolis-hastings, it would look like this : [ p0 , p1, p2 .... pn].  If we drew a histogram of this vector, it should resemble the desired distribution?

Comment: That's the right idea, but it's not a Markov chain with a finite number of states. The stationary distribution, as well as the distribution at each time step, is continuous.

Comment: ah, I think I am getting confused ... can you please write an answer if you have time this week? thank you so much for all your guidance ...

Comment: stats_noob: I'd have to review A LOT to possibly give a decent answer but one thing I can recommend is do not imagine  the existence of a transition matrix in the continous case. I think that will mess with your understanding. In the discrete case, the matrix eventually becomes a matrix that doesn't change. That's the stationary distribution in the discrete case.

Comment: But I would not try to relate the continuous case to the discrete case. Just think of the continuous case ( either gibbs sampling or MH ) as sampling from continuous distributions. The sampling is discrete but the distribution that is being reached is continuous.