# Proving the Detailed Balance Condition in Markov Processes

Tags: probability

I am trying to understand how to prove the Detailed Balance Condition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detailed_balance) in Continuous Time Markov Processes.

Here is a summary of my current understanding:

**1) Discrete State Space Markov Chain:**

- Time can be continuous or discrete
- Transition Matrix : $P$
- Countable State Space : $S$
- The chain at time $n$ is represented by $X_n$, where $X_n \in S$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

For all $n \geq 0$ and $x_0, x_1, ..., x_{n+1} \in S$, we can define the Markov property:

$$P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1} | X_0=x_0, X_1=x_1, ..., X_n=x_n) = P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1} | X_n=x_n)$$

Here, we can find out the Stationary Distribution of this Discrete Markov Chain by solving (this is a standard system of linear equations):

$$\pi = \pi \cdot P$$

**2) Continuous State Space Markov Process:**

- Time can be continuous or discrete
- State space (continuous set): $S$
- Process at time $t$ is represented by $X_t$, where $X_t \in S$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}^+$ (the set of non-negative real numbers).

I tried to write the Markov property for the Continuous State Space. For all $s \geq 0$, $t \in \mathbb{R}^+$, and$$x_u, x_{t+s} \in S$:

$$P(X_{t+s}=x_{t+s} | X_u=x_u, u \leq t) = P(X_{t+s}=x_{t+s} | X_t=x_t)$$

Here is where things get a bit complicated for me.

In the context of a continuous state space Markov chain, instead of a Transition Matrix, we use a Transition Kernel, denoted as $P(x, A)$, is defined as the probability of reaching the set $A$ from state $x$.

The transition kernel density, denoted as $$p(x, y)$$, is a non-negative function such that for all $x \in S$ and $y \in A$, the integral of $p(x, y)$ over $y$ gives the transition kernel:

$$P(x, A) = \int_{y \in A} p(x, y) \, dy$$.

$$P(x, S) = \int_{y \in S} p(x, y) \, dy = 1$$.

In other words, the transition kernel density $p(x, y)$ gives the density of the probability of transitioning from state $x$ to state $y$, and the transition kernel $P(x, A)$ gives the total probability of transitioning from state $x$ to any state in the set $A$.

This information is used to define the Stationary Distribution in a Continuous State Space Markov Process. For all $y \in S$, the Stationary Distribution $\pi(x)$ is obtained by solving (I think will be done numerically?):

$$\int_{x \in S} p(x, y)\pi(x) \, dx = \pi(y)$$

And we can now see how the Stationary Distribution is closely related to the "Detailed Balance Condition":

For all $x, y \in S$, the following equation must hold for Detailed Balance Condition to be satisfied:

$$\pi(x) p(x, y) = \pi(y) p(y, x)$$

**My Question:** For a specific $\pi(x)$ and $p(x, y)$, for all $x, y \in S$ - how do we prove that the Detailed Balance Condition is satisfied? Is there a standard approach for doing this?

Thanks!

- Note: An example of a transition kernel (Gaussian Kernel)
  $$p(x, y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$
  $$P(x, A) = \int_{y \in A} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \, dy$$

Comment: can you get this paper somewhere. I don't know if it will answer your question but I remember it helping me a lot when I was trying to understand MCMC. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2684568

Comment: thank you so much for linking this paper... I will check it out

Comment: earlier I had posted this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4852500/relationship-between-a-probability-distribution-function-and-a-probability-trans - now I think I understand the problem I was facing earlier: the interpretation of a stationary distribution is different in a continuous state space vs discrete state space. In discrete state space, the stationary distribution is a PMF (probability mass function). In continuous state space, the stationary distribution is a PDF (probability density function). With this clarification, the previous question makes a lot more sense!

Comment: I'm glad to help a little. I would read anything you can find on MCMC by chib and greenberg. The one I sent is good but I remember anything they wrote as being quite useful to understanding MCMC. I had a lot of trouble with it so don't get discouraged. Also, if you can play with a specific problem and program it, that helps sometimes also.

Comment: thank you so much for all your kind words and support - i really appreciate it. currently I am trying to teach myself more about these topics and your replies and answers are always really appreciated.

Comment: I can tell that you are really into it and doing a great job teaching yourself. The questions you ask are interesting but also kind of "deep understanding" questions so that's why I tend to recommend texts or papers. It's also because A) doing justice to these topics in this setting is not easy or B) not even sometimes possible ( for me because I either used to know it better or only know a good reference  ).

Comment: All of it is a lot to digest ( the stuff I send ) but, when you have time, check out these lecture 25 notes and then, at the same place, the lecture 26 notes. They may help with the concept of MCMC and detailed balance. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/14-384-time-series-analysis-fall-2013/resources/mit14_384f13_lec25/